# Rails 3: How Does One Restrict Access to IDs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This might be very simple; I don't know Rails very well.

I have a `match myController/myAction/myID` in my routes.rb that will direct hyperlinks to the proper page (using `link_to`). But here's the problem: I don't want people to be able to freely modify the `id` parameter, passing in via the URL whatever they like.

Is there a way to perhaps restrict access to routes to the `link_to` method only? Or maybe there's another way to go about this, using a passed in hidden variable param or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users access you site via urls like: /controller/action/:id right? A user can change an id and must not view another non authorized resource. How to achieve this?, on your controller,  return only those resources that user is allowed to access.

For example, suppose that you are using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

```
class AController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @resouces = current_user.find_all_by_id params[:id]
  end
end
```

This way if the user tries to access something he does not have access to, he will get an error.

Hope this helps, if not please let me know and I'll try to elaborate.

About **current_user**, yes it is supposed to be the current logged in user, it doesn't have to be **devise**, you can implement your own *session handling logic* and then create a helper method to retrieve the currently logged in user.

About using **devise**, if you don't want to implement your own *session handling logic*, plus if you want features like:

- remember me
- already created views that you can fully customize
- authentication
- authorization
- password encryption
- many more (please look at the [docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) for further information)

Then devise is a good way to go.

Also, it is always a great idea, if possible and as a learning exercise, implement your own **authentication and authorization layers**, you won't regret.

Best regards

Emmanuel Delgado

Comment: Could you add a sentence or two to the value of using devise. The code you have shown looks like devise is not used at all.

Comment: He is using current_user to retrieve only the current_user resources.

Comment: Added some notes to my original post, please let me know if you want me to further elaborate. Best Regards. ED.

Comment: First, thanks for the response. "A user can change an id and must not view another non authorized resource." I don't want the user to be able to type in the url to 99% of the site. There are no user logins, everyone is just browsing the site without logging in. I just want the routes to only be valid when a controller links to them somehow.

Comment: Devise is for authentication, but the question is about authorization.  These two are distinct, but related.